# Как правильно вызвать функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно вызвать функцию в Jquery, если её название записано в переменную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const $ = {
  foo: function(){console.log('invoked')}
}
const bar = 'foo'
$[bar]()
```